# open a bat file with Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

```java
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " +Main.class.getResource("/res/ActivateWindows.bat"));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opération réussie","Activation Windows 10",1);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hello everyone,here is my code it works on eclipse but when I export in .jar my application starts but when I click on the button a window appears "you will need a new application for this .jar" HELP ME

Comment: run the jar in cmd with `java -jar yourjarfile.jar` Do you have openjdk or oracle's jdk?

Comment: my app start it's not the problem it's when i click on my jbutton normally in eclipse it will start the script but when i export he doesn't work :)

Comment: how do you build it? if you are using gradle you can build the fat jar and run it (contains all the dependency) or you copy and paste the eclipse command line in your console

Comment: Windows CMD can only run a batch file which is a _file_. **An entry in a jar is not a file** (although the jar as a whole is), and CMD cannot run it. Either (1) put it in a separate file to start with, not in the jar; (2) (explicitly) copy it from the jar to an actual file and run that; or (3) if it can be run as a series of CMD _commands_ instead of a batch file, have the Java code run CMD and pass it the series of commands -- but in this case you cannot use `start` to create a new console, and instead must read the output (including errors) back from CMD and handle it yourself.

Comment: Okay thank's guy !